# Core Data DB Location Debug v Release Build

Tags: swift, core-data

I have been developing my first SWIFT MacOS App and it uses Core Data. I've just done my first release build and found that it still points at the same SQL Lite DB as my debug build. As I didn't not specify it's location I assumed (incorrectly) it would be in a different location for release.

How do I specify the location of the Database for Core Data ? Is there a way to automatically set a different location for Debug and Release ? I want to be able to run release and debug on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is have separate debug and release versions of the app. Then I can have both installed on the same device at the same time. The persistent store (and other files) use the same file names, but since they're separate apps the data is separate.

You can do this by duplicating the app target in Xcode, and making a few changes. In the list of targets, right-click your app and select "duplicate". Give the new one a similar but slightly different name. For example, maybe add "-dev" to your app's name to indicate it's the development target.

You'll also need to change the bundle ID and display name of the app. The bundle ID tells iOS it's a different app, and the display name makes it obvious which one you're tapping. You can also add a different app icon if you like.

Now you can build two versions of the app and install both on the same device. The dev version can have whatever code you're working on that's maybe still kind of broken, and the release version can be whatever's ready for release or a version downloaded from the App Store.

Comment: thank you. This sounds like what I need - I will get to look at doing as you suggest today.

Comment: Thanks. Done what you suggested and is just want I wanted.

Comment: Wonder if you can help again. This works great but I have several array controllers where I now have to changed the class names between Training_Diary.SomeClass and Training_Diary_Dev.SomeClass each time I switch the target I'm building. Is this just something I have to each time or can I keep the module the same between the two targets ?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, your CoreData database file is usually located in `Library/Application Support` within the sandboxed App. Pre iOS 10 it used to be in the `Documents` folder.

On MacOS with sandboxing enabled it's usually located at `~/Library/Containers/<app_bundle_id>/Data/Library/Application Support/<app_target_name>`

Depending on your needs, you can choose different locations for each of your persistent stores when you setup the CoreData stack.

However, I don't see any reason to choose different store locations for different *Build Configurations*. Thats not the purpose for *Build Configurations* anyway. Your database will end up being exactly the same - it cannot be affected by build settings.

I would also not recommend to use different store locations for any purpose - except perhaps when you perform Unit Tests.

What you can do however, is to set certain environment flags that affect CoreData's behaviour, for example that enables Thread Violation Assertions. You do this in Xcode Schemes - not in the build settings. Note, that a scheme uses a certain Build Configuration, say Release or Debug and that the name for the scheme *can* be the same which is often confusing.

You should ensure that these helpful assertions that you can set in a Scheme are not enabled when you build a release. ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the approach then if I want to run my app and also work on the next version on the same machine? I would want each to point at a different Core Data Database.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly and whether you refer to iOS or Mac OS. Thus, made some clarifications - please see my edits. But each app (instance on your device) uses its own database. Even with Sandboxing enabled, it's possible for two or more apps to share the same database instance, but you must explicitly declare this (see App Sandboxing for more details).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I am using MacOS. I think i may not be clear. I have an app which I now want to use. Currently I'm running it via Xcode. Instead I want to have a 'release' version (I may be using this term incorrectly) - ie I build the app and then stick it my dock and run that day to day. At the same time I want to be developing new features (which may include additions to core data) - thus I want my development version pointing at a different Core Data SQLite DB. I think I just assumed building for release v debug would do this for me.

Comment: You may consider to handle this within a "deployment process". Suppose, your database path points to your development path in your master and topic branches. When considering a release version you could branch from your master to a release branch, setup the final path and deploy this to the app store.

Comment: thanks - thats a great suggestion. At the moment it's only being deployed to me !! but if I decide to make it a little more public I will look in to doing this